# Unable to create a Fluent ORM query for querying nested parents

Tags: swift, postgresql, fluent, vapor, vapor-fluent

I have 3 tables, LastName, MiddleName and FirstName... FirstName has MiddleNameID as Parent, MiddleName has LastName.id as parent

Models look like this

```
final class LastName: Model, Content {
    static let schema = "lastnames"
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?

    @Field(key: "name")
    var name: String

    
    @Children(for: \.$lastname)
    var middle_names: [MiddleName]
    
    init() { }

    init(id: UUID? = nil, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

final class MiddleName: Model, Content {
    static let schema = "middlenames"
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?

    @Parent(key: "last_name_id")
    var lastname: LastName
    
    @Field(key: "name")
    var name: String

    @Children(for: \.$middleNameId)
    var firstNames: [FirstName]
    
    init() { }

    init(id: UUID? = nil, lastname: LastName, name: String ) {
        self.id = id
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.name = name
    }
}


final class FirstName: Model, Content {
    static let schema = "firstnames"
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?
    
    @Parent(key: "middle_name_id")
    var middleNameId: MiddleName
    
    
    @Field(key: "name")
    var name: String
   
    
    init() { }

    init(id: UUID? = nil, middleNameId: MiddleName, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.middleNameId = testBundleId
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

And i want the query such as give me all the first name records where lastname == Smith AND/OR middle == James... not sure how can I do a multiple join's using Fluent DSL? or maybe give me all first name which matches something from Middle Name and/or last name

if I had to write a SQL query probably will look like this

```
                  SELECT DISTINCT ON (ln.id, mn.id)
                  ln.name, mn.name, fn.*
                  FROM last_name ln
                  LEFT JOIN middle_name mn ON ln.id = mn.last_name_id
                  LEFT JOIN first_name fn ON fn.middle_name_id = mn.id
                  WHERE ( mn.name <> '' AND fn.name <> '' ) AND
                  (true AND ln.name ~ 'smith')
                  ORDER BY ln.id, mn.id, fn.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a Fluent query, something like:

```swift
return Lastname.query(on: req)
    .filter(\.$name == "Smith")
    .with(\.$middle_names) { $0.with(\.$firstnames) }
    .all()
    .flatMap { wholeNames in
    let result = wholeNames.filter { $0.middle_names.contains("James") }
    // continue
}
```

This will give you all the Smiths who have a middle name of James. You can use it as the basis for the OR variant. It works by first filtering the surnames for Smith and then the `with` joins the middle name, but the closure ensures first names are joined as well.

I don't think there is a way of building the middle-name filter into the query, so I think you have to do it as I have shown.

Comment: @Schoolteacher Thanks! is there a way I can add `.unique` on LastName.MiddleName combo to so I can only get 1 LastName, MiddleName with a latest on First name.?